# Creating new data in a table and do a fit

Tags: gnuplot

I want to do the following:

I have a data set following a Gaussian line shape, but there are some data which is strongly deviating. For the resulting fit these data points should not be included.

So my idea is to create 2 Gaussian's one above and one below as a restriction. So that just all data points lying between these 2 Gaussians are considered in the fit and the rest outside not.

[image]

I can easily create 2 Gaussians and create these data in a table by using:
(notice: data=data file)

```
set table '1.Gauss'                  
plot g(x)+0.1   
unset table  
set table '2.Gauss'  
plot g(x)-0.1  
unset table  
set table 'all'  
plot '1.Gauss', '2.Gauss', 'data'  
unset table
```

But then: all data is listed one by another. Moreover i don't know how to fit later by saying just use this data if its between these 2 Gaussians.

Do you have any other idea?

**ADDITION:**

Iam not really into programming or gnuplot so i have difficulties to understand your messages. So here is all of my programming in gnuplot:

```
    set xrange [1038.6603:1038.666]
    set yrange [0.8:1.3]
    file="data"   
    g(x) = N0*(A*exp(-(x-(b+d))2/(2*sigma2)))+c  
    N0=0.2; b=1038.66315;d=0.00001; c=1; A=3; sigma=0.0001

    filterData(y,m,M)=((yM)? 1/0 : y)  
    fit h(x) file using 1:(filterData($2,g($1)-0.1,g($1)+0.1)) via N0,d,c,A,sigma 
    plot file using 1:(filterData($2,g($1)-0.1,g($1)+0.1)) g(x)-0.1, g(x)+1, h(x)
```

In the second to last row, gnuplot says: " undefined variable: x"

I know that something is of course missing or wrong, but i don't know really how to solve. Could maybe comment your lines too? So that a layman as me can understood it?
Thank you :)

**HERE 2ND ADDITION:**

here is all of my text:

```
    set xrange [1038.6598:1038.6663]
    set yrange [0.8:1.3]
    set fit errorvariables
    file= "09_05_16-10.thzpp"        
    g(x) = N0*(A*exp(-(x-(b+d))**2/(2*sigma**2)))+c
    N0=0.2; b=1038.66315;d=0.00001; c=1; A=3; sigma=0.0001
    filterData(y,m,M)=((y<m||x>M)? 1/0 : y)
    fit h(x) file using 1:(filterData($2,g($1)-0.1,g($1)+0.1)) via N0,d,c,A,sigma 
    plot file using 1:(filterData($2,g($1)-0.1,g($1)+0.1)), g(x)-0.1, g(x)+1, h(x)
```

This gives me the error "in line 8: undefined variable: x"

So my data is in x-range between : [1038.6598:1038.6663]. When i delete the last 3 lines and just use instead:

```
   fit [1038.6603:1038.666] [0.95:1.2] g(x) file via N0,d,c,A,sigma
   plot file title 'Messung', g(x) title 'Fit'
```

it works, but i dont have this nice 2 Gaussian restriction.

So what is wrong in my upper text?

Comment: There is at least one typo in your formula for `g`, the `2` after a parenthesis. Please copy-paste exactly your code. Also, your x-range does not make much sense, if your data is really between x=1038.6603 and x=1038.666 and was obtained by floating point calculation with double-precision arithmetic, I fear that the relative error on x will be huge. And this may also be a problem for the fit. You should reset the origin of this frequency data from.

Comment: Here it gives 'undefined function h(x)' rather. You need to define it. The reason why I've introduced it in my answer below is that you can't adjust g(x) by fitting while using is at the same time to filter...

Comment: yes i did,, but it doesnt help.  Can someone please help me?

Comment: Just noted, there's an `x` in `filterData(y,m,M)=((y<m||x>M)? 1/0 : y)` which should be a `y`, `filterData(y,m,M)=((y<m||y>M)? 1/0 : y)`.

Comment: I found this mistake yesterday :) now it is WORKING :D !!! great, thank you!  BUT... the following is really serious: If i use the fit with 2 Gaussians, my error is bigger than without the Gaussians. But it should be the other way around. Do you know why?

Comment: Filtering the data before fitting is not appropriate I believe. How are the parameters of `g` chosen? Anyhow, this is not a question for superuser.SE! (Btw, think of voting up/accepting useful answers)

Comment: @Joce ...it is an unregistered user... I have doubt Mattes will be back soon. Take my vote(s) instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter data by creating a function something like:

```
min_value = 1
max_value = 2
filterData(x)=(x < min_value || x > max_value) ? (1/0) : (x)
plot 'data' u 1:(filterData($2))
```

The ternary operator: `(is this true) ? it is true : it is false` and `1/0` is undefined which gnuplot will silently ignore.

(not tested)

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you would need to save the Gaussians into files, you can work directly using your Gauss function `g`.

As you want to compare your data with the two Gaussians, your filtering function needs to be given max and min value at the position considered:

```
filterData(y,m,M)=((y<m||y>M)? 1/0 : y)
```

Then you can plot and/or fit:

```
fit h(x) 'data' using 1:(filterData($2,g($1)-0.1,g($1)+0.1)) via ...
plot 'data' using 1:(filterData($2,g($1)-0.1,g($1)+0.1)), \
     g(x)-0.1, \
     g(x)+0.1, \
     h(x)
```